# How to schedule task with dynamic time though rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

My main problem is to set dynamic scheduler through rufus-scheduler, let suppose i have a text fields on which we put minutes, base on that minutes re-schedule rufus-scheduler.

Comment: you can add in ENV?